# Passing PFObject between custom class to viewController before UITableView is appearing

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm building an iOS app with swift 2 and Xcode 7, I want to separate between the MODEL and CONTROLLER. Therefore, I have built a custom class that query a data from **Parse** and loads an array[which found in the `ViewController` class].

The issue is - the `UITableView` which found in `ViewController` class loads empty to the iPhone screen because the array is supposed to be fill with `PFObject` doesn't make it until than. The output is: the array load with objects after the tableview is viewing on the screen therefor it's empty table view.

I need to know how to cause the screen wait from viewing until the `UITableView` is loading with the object.

Custom Class to query the data from parse.

```
import Foundation
import Parse
import ParseTwitterUtils

class ParseQueryObject {

    init(className:String) {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Tasks")            
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (taskLista:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                taskList = taskLista as [PFObject]!
            } 
            else {
                print(error?.description)
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

ViewController :

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseTwitterUtils

var taskList = [PFObject]()


class TaskListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

var userAccount:PFUser?

@IBOutlet weak var addNewTaskView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var twitterUserNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.textField.delegate = self

    //let name = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.screenName
    //self.twitterUserNameLabel?.text = "@ \(name!)"

    self.twitterUserNameLabel.text = userAccount?.username

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

        ParseQueryObject.init(className: "Tasks")
    }

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default

}


func addNewTask() {

    if self.textField.text == "" {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "You need to add task first.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        let newTask = PFObject(className:"Tasks")

        newTask["description"] = textField.text

        if PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.screenName == nil {

             newTask["taskUserName"] = userAccount?.username

        } else {

            newTask["taskUserName"] = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.screenName

        }


        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false

        newTask.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if (success) {

                taskList.insert(newTask, atIndex: 0)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

                self.textField.text = ""

                self.textField.resignFirstResponder()

                self.tableView.reloadData()


            } else {

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "there is an error", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        }

    }



}

func alert() {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "Now you can create your own tasks.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Let's Start it!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    addNewTask()

    return false

    }

@IBAction func addNewTaskTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    addNewTask()

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    super.view.endEditing(true)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    super.view.endEditing(true)

}

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return taskList.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    let taskObj = taskList[indexPath.row]

    let user = taskObj["User"] as? PFUser

    do {

        try user?.fetchIfNeeded()

    } catch{}


    cell.textLabel?.text = taskObj.objectForKey("description") as? String

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let delete = taskList[indexPath.row]

    delete.deleteInBackground()

    taskList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

}

Comment: we will need some code here. Please edit your question with the whole model and controller.

Comment: the code were added.

Comment: add in your viewDidLoad -> self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView() ... you are probably seeing "ghost cells" as you stated that the rows in section is taskList.count and if taskList is empty your tableView will show this cells until it has real ones.

Comment: You are calling the tableView delegate and datasource two times, remove the second one.

Comment: @ Marcos Griselli - didn't get the first one, for the second i have delete it , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's an excellent start.  The key idea is to realize that functions that run asynchronously often need to tell their caller that they've finished.  Your view controller needs to know so it can reload the tableView.  Like parse's sdk, your querying `init` method ought to be declared with a callback...

```
func init(className:String, completion: (results:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void) {
    // your code as you have it, then, when inside the find...
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { // ...
        if error == nil {
            taskList = taskLista as [PFObject]!
            completion(results:taskLista, error:nil)
        }
        // ...
}
```

Now your view controller can know when the query is done, and therefore, when to update the UI...

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
ParseQueryObject.init(className: "Tasks" completion: { (taskLista:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for better clarification of code responsibility, `init` should always put initializing codes rather than making a call and have a completion for indicating the finish of loading data. I would think that's the finish of the initializing process. Instead, you can have another method like so `func loadData(completion: (results:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void)`.

Whatever you have written does not have problem except not calling `reloadData()` from `UITableView`.